# How to move to next page of forum posts using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

can anybody help me?

I am trying to gather posts from a Chinese discussion forum. I've written code to open the forum posts and get the text of each post. This works well for Page 1.

I then want to move to the next page: the 'button' for this has class="next z-enable", so I think I need to use xpath to locate it, but then when I do Selenium doesn't seem go click to go to the next page of this. Is the button java script or something?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://comment.tie.163.com/EIU9CP4R0001875O.html')
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rgt-col")
for idx, x in enumerate(posts):
    content = str(x.text)
    print(content)
    with open(''+str(idx)+'post.txt', 'w') as g:
        g.write(content)

time.sleep(20)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tie-main']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[6]/span")
element.click()
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated! I'm new to Python / Selenium, but trying to learn as fast as I can. Thank you...

Comment: Not sure if your xpath is correct... It looks very long and complicated. If the class name is unique, you can shorten it a lot. Regarding your question: you execute `element.click()`, but element is undefined?! I guess, it should be `element = driver.find_element_(...)`?

Comment: This doesn’t look like a Xpath name.

Comment: Could you share with us the page you're scraping, please? (The webaddress)

Comment: @NielsHenkens Partially agree... This looks like an xpath that is taken from Firefox' developer options (Inspect Element -> Copy -> Xpath). These are automatically generated and often much more complicated than they have to be.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your replies. This is the page: http://comment.tie.163.com/EIU9CP4R0001875O.html 
To get the xpath for the next page button, I used Chrome's inspect elements, and then the 'copy xpath' - is there a better way to get it?

Comment: @nostradamus Ah, thanks for the info! Never used that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on `Next`. Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and following xapth.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='tie-head']//ul[@class='m-page']//li//span[@class='next z-enable']"))).click()
```

You need to add following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works, and I really appreciate the help sorting this out

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of [time.sleep](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/) as it will speed up your test so Selenium will be able to proceed to next page as soon as the button will be clickable
2. Consider using relative XPath and try to avoid these `div[2]/div[2]/div[2]` as your current approach is fragile and sensitive to any markup change. For example you could use [XPath contains()](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) function

Suggested code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'z-enable'")))
element.click()
```

Comment: Thank you! Both your (and @KunduK's similar) solution work really well. I appreciate the help sorting this out!